# ERR: error while loading shared libraries: libjulia.so.1: cannot open shared object file [Julia] - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile. It has a tool called Atria that utilizes Julia. Since Ubuntu 22.04 does not have Julia package, I had to resort to installing it. The following is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install tzdata
RUN apt-get update &&\
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get -y install tzdata

# Install Python, Bowtie2 and Java
RUN apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip \ 
    openjdk-8-jdk  \ 
    bowtie2 \ 
    wget

RUN  apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
     zlib1g-dev \
     libbz2-dev \
     liblzma-dev  

# Install RSeQC
RUN pip3 install RSeQC

# Install biopython=1.80
RUN pip3 install biopython

#Install Julia
RUN wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.8/julia-1.8.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf julia-1.8.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    mv julia-1.8.1/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/julia

RUN /sbin/ldconfig -v

# Install Atria
RUN wget https://github.com/cihga39871/Atria/releases/download/v3.1.2/atria-3.1.2-linux.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxf atria-3.1.2-linux.tar.gz && \
    mv atria-3.1.2/bin/atria /usr/local/bin/atria && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/atria

#Atria dependencies
RUN  apt-get install pigz pbzip2

# Install findtail
 RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/findtail/findtail_v1.01 && \
     mv findtail_v1.01 /usr/local/bin/findtail_v1.01 && \
     chmod +x /usr/local/bin/findtail_v1.01 
# Cleanup 
RUN apt clean
```

What I have tried so far is :

1. Julia v1.6.7 and v1.8.4
2. `RUN /sbin/ldconfig -v` as suggested [here](https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/)

How to fix it? Should I try to install Julia using PPA?

edit- The error:

```
root@b0f4b17a7c18:/# atria
/usr/local/bin/julia: error while loading shared libraries: libjulia.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It is recognizing the atria command tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make sure you include the required library files when you install Atria. Since you're not building any software (i.e. using `make`), the usual way is to simply move the directory under `/opt` and add the executable(s) to your `PATH` using the [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) keyword. Note that Julia comes bundled with Atria, so all you need is:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    bowtie2 \
    openjdk-8-jdk \
    pbzip2 \
    pigz \
    python3.10 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-biopython \
    wget \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install RSeQC
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir RSeQC

# Install Atria
RUN wget -q https://github.com/cihga39871/Atria/releases/download/v3.1.2/atria-3.1.2-linux.tar.gz \
    && tar xf atria-3.1.2-linux.tar.gz \
    && mv atria-3.1.2 /opt/atria

# Install findtail
RUN wget -q https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/findtail/findtail_v1.01 \
    && chmod +x findtail_v1.01 \
    && mv findtail_v1.01 /usr/local/bin/findtail 

# Add the Atria executable to the PATH
ENV PATH="/opt/atria/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Hello @Steve, thank you for that. I'm still a novice (obviously lol) trying to wrap my head around this stuff and I so appreciate your time and effort in helping me out.

Comment: I don't understand what modifications to make, as the question and answer are rather sizeable files, can you show a more minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

Just to note `RUN apt clean`  ... is much better performed using `&& apt clean`, like in @Steve's approach, recommended for complicated reasons.

**Suggestion**: what about using the official Julia Docker as the base rather than create it from scratch? There isn't a Ubuntu Julia but there is a Debian base.

```
docker run -it --rm Julia
```

or

```
docker pull julia
```

or via a Dockerfile,

```
FROM Julia:buster
```

or

```
FROM Julia:latest
```

Comment: Doesn't work when you want to layer Julia on top of an existing image that contains a lot of stuff you don't wont to re-layer on the Julia base image